# Show that every odd prime divisor p of $N^2+1024$ satisfies $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ regardless of the choice of $N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that every odd prime divisor $P$ of $N^2+1024$ satisfies $P \equiv 1\ \pmod 4$ regardless of the choice of N.

Maybe Wilson's theorem and FLT are needed. But I have no idea to deal with it.

Any hints are appreciated.

Are the following steps correct?

The link to my steps:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19zECq3U9paxC67cCz7sK89DArE87Y6ko/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Compute $(-1024)^{(p-1)/2}$ mod $p$, and recall $1024=32^2$.

Comment: Why do "Compute (−1024)^(p−1)/2 mod p"? And, what are theorems I should use?

Comment: Use FLT, and $-1024=N^2$...